# DevTools was disconnected from page while using 'onchange'

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-core

I'm currently receiving an error whilst trying to fill a cascading select list who's javascript function is triggered by the on change of the previous list however the every time the controller returns the json object back to Ajax callback, Google Chrome DevTools is throwing the error:

```
DevTools was from the page
Once page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect
```

I have tried to enable logs and run Chrome using the flags however nothing is ever logged, nothing is saved in the logs in the Network tab either.

I have tested populating the select tag through adding a submit button to the first dropdown and calling/ populating the second dropdown that way and that seems to work fine. Is there any reason that using `onchange` on the `Html.DropDownListFor()` would cause DevTools to throw this error?

The PartialView containing the code (I have added both techniques I have used):

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Country</label>

        <!--  This works in filling the second dropdownlist. -->
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.Country, "FieldID", "Value"), new { @id = "_ddlCountries", @class = "fr-select" })
        <button type="submit" onclick="javascript: GetCities()">Test</button> 
        <!-- **********************************************  -->

        <!-- This does not work in filling the second dropdown -->
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.Country, "FieldID", "Value"), new { @id = "_ddlCountries", @class = "fr-select", onchange="javascript: GetCities()" })
        <!-- **********************************************  -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select City</label>
        <select class="fr-select" id="_cities"></select>
    </div>
```

Both get into the javascript function below but the `onchange` throws the DevTools message/ error:

```
function GetCities() {
    debugger;

    var ddlText = $('#_ddlCountries option:selected').text();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCities", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(ddlText),
        contentType: 'Application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;

            //Create a markup for a select
            var markup = "";

            //Populate the markup
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                markup += "<option Value=" + result[i].FieldID + ">" + result[i].Value + "</option>";
            }

            //Populate dropdown with value
            $("#_cities").html(markup).show();
        }
    })
}
```

Controller action:

```
    public ActionResult GetCities([FromBody] string ddlText)
    {
        List<FieldMap> cities = new List<FieldMap>();
        cities.Add(new FieldMap
        {
            FieldID = 0,
            Value = "-- Please Select a City --"
        });

        foreach (var city in _uploadedFileModel.cities.Where(x => x.name == ddlText).OrderBy(x => x.city.name))
        {
            cities.Add(new FieldMap
            {
                FieldID = cities.Select(x => x.FieldID).Max() + 1,
                Value = city.name
            });
        }

        return Json(cities);
    }
```

This works using MVC framework but for some reason it doesn't with Core. Is there any reason why the `onchange` would be triggering this error?

Comment: Does it work when debuging in Edge or IE?